# jQuery pseudo selector with variable as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set a variable equal to a frequently-referenced selector:

```
var allSteps = $("#makeIntoSlideshowUL > li");
```

Additionally, I'm using a custom-defined search function that makes contains (which I'm using to search) case-insensitive

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
```

Without using the variable selector, I can do this

```
$("#makeIntoSlideshowUL > li:Contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").css("display","block");
```

How do I use the variable selector and this defined psuedo selector together?  I've tried this, but it doesn't work

```
allSteps+":Contains('" + $(this).val() + "')".css("display","block");
```

Comment: try with `allSteps.filter(":Contains('" + $(this).val() + "'").css("display","block");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$(allSteps.selector + ":Contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with your custom selector:

```
allSteps.filter(":Contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var expression = allSteps+":Contains('" + $(this).val() + "')".css("display","block");
alert($(expression).length);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Just evaluate the expression into a variable first - and then go with it.

=H=